# Audio through iec958 super quiet

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I've tried a lot of things I can find, but nothing helps.

Problem in Ubuntu 14.04:

Audio plays fine through `HDMI`, but not through `s/pdif`.
When I unlock and raise the left front or right front volume, the audio comes in noticeably louder in the speaker that I raise, but when both are set at the same volume level, I can only hear it if I bring the speaker close to my ear, no matter how high I set the volume -- it almost sounds muffled.

What's really strange is some YouTube videos come through loud and clear and some just like I described the problem. Seems like it depends on the bit-rate or codec the audio stream is encoded in.

I have everything unmuted in `alsamixer` and raised all the way up and High Definition Audio Controller is set to `off`. The digital/optical cable is going from computer's headphone jack to my receiver.

*How should I proceed?*